# Compacion De 2 Fechas En Java Netbeans y Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Quiero hacer una comparación de 2 fechas, la primera fecha esta declarada en un SimpleDateFormat y la segunda es una fecha guardada en una base de datos mysql.
Ahora, el problema es que hice una consulta de la base de datos trayendo la fecha almacenada en mysql y poniendola en un label, cree un if y un else para efectuar la comparacion, pero solo realiza la parte del if.
Asi que mi duda es, ¿Que se tiene que hacer para validar la comparacion o estoy dejando ir algo?. Espero y puedan ayudarme.

Aqui el codigo :

```
public class Prueba extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {

    String Horas,Minutos,Segundos;
    Thread Hilo;

    Conectar cc = new Conectar();
    Connection cn = cc.conexion();

    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    Statement st;

    public Prueba() {
        initComponents();
        try{
        String Fecha="";
        String cons="SELECT * FROM fecha";
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(cons);
        while(rs.next())
            {
            Fecha=rs.getString(1);
            }
            Lbl_Fecha1.setText(Fecha);
            }catch(SQLException e)
            {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        Lbl_Fecha.setText(Fecha());
        Hilo=new Thread(this);
        Hilo.start();
        setVisible(true);
        if(cn == null){
            Lbl_Conexion.setText("Sin Conexion");
        }else{
            Lbl_Conexion.setText("Activa");
        }
        if(Lbl_Fecha.equals(Lbl_Fecha1)){
            Lbl_Aviso.setText("Expiro Tu Licencia");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sigue Disfrutando");
        }
    }

    public void Hora(){
    Calendar Calendario=new GregorianCalendar();
    Date HoraActual=new Date();
    Calendario.setTime(HoraActual);
    Horas=Calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>9?""+Calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY):"0"+Calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    Minutos=Calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE)>9?""+Calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE):"0"+Calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    Segundos=Calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND)>9?""+Calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND):"0"+Calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }

    public void run(){
        Thread current=Thread.currentThread();
        while(current==Hilo){
            Hora();
            Lbl_Hora.setText(Horas+":"+Minutos+":"+Segundos);
        }
    } 

    public static String Fecha(){
        Date Fecha=new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat FormatoFecha=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");
        return FormatoFecha.format(Fecha);
    }                                      

private void Btn_GuardarFechaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO fecha(Fechas) VALUES (?)";
        try{
            PreparedStatement st = cn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            st.setString(1,((JTextField)JDC_Fecha.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            st.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fecha Guardada Correctamente");
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Al Guardar La Fecha");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aquí `Lbl_Fecha.equals(Lbl_Fecha1)` estas comparando los objetos en vez de los `.getText()`

Comment: Gracias, Funciono!. Llevaba Atorado Un Buen Rato En Esto